# Returns the first element of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How do I return the first element of a list in haskell?

I'm using https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_haskell_online.php to compile my code.

This is what I have so far.

```hs
main = head ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

head :: [a] -> a
head [] = error "runtime"
head (x:xs) = x
```

It's giving me the following error:

```
$ghc -O2 --make *.hs -o main -threaded -rtsopts
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

main.hs:1:8: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘head’
    It could refer to either ‘Prelude.head’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at main.hs:1:1
                             (and originally defined in ‘GHC.List’)
                          or ‘Main.head’, defined at main.hs:4:1
```

Comment: the problem is that `head [1,2,3,4,5]` can refer both to the `head` you defined or the one implemented from the `Prelude`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that `head [1,2,3,4,5]` can refer both to the `head` you defined or the one implemented from the `Prelude`.

You can disambiguate by specifying the module:

```
module Main where

main = print (Main.head [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

You can furthermore not use <s>`main = Main.head [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`</s>, since the type of a `main` is `IO a` with `a` an arbitrary type.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly import `Prelude` without `head`, preventing the name clash with your version.

```
import Prelude hiding (head)

head :: [a] -> a
head [] = error "runtime"
head (x:xs) = x

main = print $ head [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```